# Cost of production

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Assume that a producer knows that the total manufacturing cost of 1000 units of his product is 8,500 dollars , while the total cost of manufacturing 2000 units is 11,500 dollars. Assuming that this relationship between the cost and the number of manufactured units is linear, find the relationship, graph the equation and interpret the graph. What is the total cost of production of 2500 units?

Comment: Some effort done ? no idea at all ?

Comment: You have two "points" $(1000, 8.500)$ and $(2000, 11.500)$ and the info that the relationship between units produced and total cost is *linear*. What does it mean "linear" ?

Comment: Using those two points I can found the slope and gave me 3. And after that I can write an equation to find the value of y.

Comment: To "graph the equation" must also be quite easy : draw the two points and then the line joining them.

Comment: Finally compute the point $(2500,y)$.

Comment: My equation will be $y-8500=3(x-1000)$.   Then I replace 2500 for x and find that the value of $y=13000$. But then how can I interpret my graph?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use $y=mx+c$ for both the points where $m$ is the slope and $c$ is the $y-intercept$.

$m={x_2-x_1 \over {y_2-y_1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

*This will be the graph and the equations. X-axis represents the units and y-axis represent the  cost of manufacturing.*

**But how I interpret the graph?**

[image]